# Why does C++ not allow a parameter to be a default argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-design, default-parameters

```
void g(int n, decltype(n) = 0); // ok
void f(int n, int = n); // error : default argument references parameter 'n'

int main()
{
    f(1); // want it to be same as f(1, 1);
}
```

Why does C++ not allow a parameter to be a default argument?

**What's the rationale?**

Comment: I don't know, if I am getting this wrong but **void f(int n, int = n);** has a syntax error in it, moreover you shouldn't assign an integer in a function to another integer if it isn't initialized. Try declaring a global variable int x=1 and then assign it as a default argument.

Comment: I reopened. The duplicate did not deal the rationale behind this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One often-quoted potential rationale for that restriction is as follows: allowing parameters as default arguments would require imposing at least a partial ordering on parameter evaluation. Parameters that are used as default arguments in other parameters would have to be evaluated first.

Meanwhile, C++ continues to stick to the original parameter evaluation approach: parameters are evaluated in *unspecified* order.

The very same reasoning can be used to explain why one cannot refer to class members in default arguments of member functions: that would impose some ordering requirements on evaluation of hidden parameter `this`.